# capture time remove the tool bar

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

```
-(IBAction)printDisplay:(id)sender{

     CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0,44.0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);

    NSValue *rectObj = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect];

    

    CGRect rectRestored = [rectObj CGRectValue];

    

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(rectRestored.size.width, rectRestored.size.height-44));

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);

}
```

This is code for capture the image from the current screen.

Problem is that I don't want to get the UIToolBar for the capture into the screen for that what to do. My application screenshot looks like this :

[image]

and after I take a screenshot of the image :

[image]

In short I want the remove the UIToolBar when the snap of the image.
Thanx in advance for spend your valuable time.

@samuel

Comment: are you displaying that image in an UIImageView?

Comment: yes right now it's image view but, suppose their may be multiple controls are exits:-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the image frame is starting from below the Toolbar, you can just set the rect starting from  (0,44). If the image frame is starting from beneath the toolbar from (0.0) just set the `toolbarObject.hidden = YES;` before taking the screenshot through graphicsContext and reset it back to `toolbarObject.hidden = NO;` afterwards.

Comment: why we need to play with Hide property? We can keep imageview's and other controls into different view and then capture that view only.

Comment: @Devang see that's the developer's part. you can surely achieve same output by various methods so that's no offense I guess!!

Answer (score 0):

Keep your images and extra stuff(what ever contain you want to capture) in different view and use that view for capture.

In your code lets say Second View named as secondView So code will be :

```
-(IBAction)printDisplay:(id)sender{

     CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0,44.0,self.secondView.frame.size.width,self.secondView.frame.size.height);
     NSValue *rectObj = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect];
     CGRect rectRestored = [rectObj CGRectValue];

     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(rectRestored.size.width, rectRestored.size.height-44));
     [self.secondView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
     viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code so that the line

```
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

is

```
[imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```